# Can end users specify where to save games' data?

Tags: windows, path, command-line-arguments, portable-apps, unity3d

This [freeware Unity Engine game](https://turbochimp.itch.io/space-quest-3d) saves in Windows its data at:

1. **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Turbo Chimp**
2. **%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Turbo Chimp**
3. The registry key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Turbo Chimp**

Are there general Unity command line parameters that might allow specifying different paths (e.g. **game.exe -save_to=c:\games**) or allow to use a file like **game.ini** to specify where to save?

This is because I prefer to run programs in a portable way (if all else fails, I might use PortableApps to create a launcher).

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow` is probably the default path for Unity, then the sub-dir is created per game. Can you not set the path of 1 to be `c:\games` and 2 to be `c:\games\documents`?

Comment: From what I read on Unity 1 is the default while 2 isn't, and yet this specific game writes to both. In any case, this is a question for end users, so what do you mean if can set? You have access to the game, it's a freeware, so feel free to modify anything you want there as an end user.

Comment: I'm suggesting you edit the paths in the registry.

Comment: The aforementioned registry key contains no paths. If you refer to changing the general path of %USERPROFILE% (there's no other environmental variable there), changing it in the registry will affect all the other apps. In any case, you can change it temporarily too (`set USERPROFILE=c:\something` then run the game in the same session), but I don't think it will help because it doesn't seem Unity uses this variable directly).